# The best way to handle hover image with onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a button that shows a image and when hovering another image is shown. This can be done with both link(a) and a regular element with class/onmouseover/onmouseout events. A link is only used when redirecting to a URL so if I need to use OnClick(for calling function) I should use a regular element with onmouse events right?

The problem is that when the ajax call is dune I need to change the class/onmouseover/onmouseout of two buttons and that will be alot of jquery code.

So how do I solve this as easy as possible?

Comment: Use eventhandlers, always

Comment: you don't need class/onmouseover/onmouseout events to change an image, css `:hover` can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `a` tag for `onclick`, just give `"javascript:void(0)"` in `href` attribute, and changing classes will not be a lot of jquery code, its just few lines code.

```
$("#elementid").attr("class","newclass")
$("#elementid").attr("onmouseover","newvalue")
$("#elementid").attr("onmouseout","newvalue")
```

**CSS WAY**

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="function()" id="idAnchor"></a>
```

CSS:

```
a#idAnchor{
display:block;
width:50px; /*width of your image*/
height:50px; /*height of your image*/
background:url("imagepath");
}

a#idAnchor:hover{
background:url("newimagepath");
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2QS3M/1/)

Comment: is the "javascript:void(0)" fully suported? No for one button its not alot of code but for 2 buttons in 3 possible states it will be 6 times the code you showed.

Comment: Yes it is fully supported, it will not create any issue :)

Comment: if you give "#" in href then you will face the issue of page going to top which is fixed by `javascript:void(0)` Also are you using mouseover and mouseout to change the images?

Comment: you can also manage image change through css, give width to anchor tag, and give the image as background, then on hover you can give another background image, this will work

Comment: Yes Im using mouseover and mouseout to change the class of the element. A regular link with javascript:void(0) sounds like a solution but will it work on all browsers? And is this the best way?

Comment: could you give a example and the second solution?

Comment: It works in IE, Mozila, CHrome, Opera and it is really widely used so you can go with it :)

Comment: If you don't like javascript:void(0) (I think it's really ugly), if you're using jQuery anyway you can use href="#" and `.preventDefault()`

Comment: I used hover of the CSS on a regular div element and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure how AJAX changes anything. Are you dynamically generating new buttons through AJAX ? Can you show us the code ?

Using jQuery's AJAX function shouldn't be much of a problem.

```
$.ajax({  type: "POST",  url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    // change your button classes here
    $(".button1").addClass("class1");
    $(".button1").removeClass("class2");
});
```

And use the :hover CSS pseudo class, if you are just changing an image. That's much faster than doing it through mousehover event.

Comment: Right now I got 2 elements with class/mouseover/mouseout set where the two last events will change the class of the element. The buttons can have 3 states, hover, regular and inactive. When clicking a element the Ajax call will run and then the class/mouseover/mouseout of both of the elements needs to be changed based on the new status. If the CSS :hover is sequred to use on all browsers over IE6 that seems to be the esiest way.